# PhantomJS - Get screen captures from many URL

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have this code in capture.js file :

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var ii = 1;
page.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', function() {page.render('capture_' + ii + '.png');}); ii++;
page.open('http://github.com/',        function() {page.render('capture_' + ii + '.png');}); ii++;
page.open('http://google.com/',        function() {page.render('capture_' + ii + '.png');}); ii++;
phantom.exit();
```

That code produces nothing.

How do I have to write the js file to get the screen capture from a list of URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this because Javascript is async by nature. You should open a new page only when the previous is loaded (in the callback).

The easiest way render your three pages may be :

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', function() {
    page.render('capture_stackoverflow.png');
     page.open('http://github.com/',        function() {
        page.render('capture_github.png');
        page.open('http://google.com/',        function() {
            page.render('capture_google.png');
            phantom.exit();
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Take a look at the official [render_multi_url.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/render_multi_url.js) example.